# How to perform exact phrase search on a Antora generated site offline?

Tags: antora

Wanted to know if there is any Antora extension that supports exact phrase search on Antora generated site in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, none currently exists.

The existing `antora-lunr` extension provides code that creates an index during site generation, and uses `lunr.js` as the search library when browsing the generated site. `lunr.js` does not support exact phrase search, which is where the limitation exists.

To solve your problem, I'd suggest that you find a library that provide exact phrase search in an offline site, and then figure out how to create an Antora extension that builds the correct index and injects the necessary CSS/JS into the active theme.

That's no simple task, but the `antora-lunr` extension demonstrates all of the non-search parts that would be required. See: https://gitlab.com/antora/antora-lunr-extension

As for a search library, this might be a contender: https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch
But, since the project hasn't been updated in a while, and is incomplete, it's hard to say how much work would be involved it getting it to work.

Comment: https://pagefind.app/ seems promising. When I get a chance to try it out, I'll update my answer.